# How to pass Enum to ParameterGrid?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-multiprocessing, hyperparameters

I would like to pass several parameters to a function that should be optimized  via hyperparameters and `multiprocessing`.

This fails if an `Enum`  is passed as a parameter. See code below.

How can I pass an `Enum` in this case?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
from multiprocessing import Pool
from enum import Enum


class MyStrategy(Enum):
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2


var1 = MyStrategy(1)
var2 = MyStrategy(2)
abc = [1, 2]
xyz = [3, 4]
if True:
    pg = [{'variant': var1,
           'abc': abc,
           'xyz': xyz, },
          {'variant': var2,
           'abc': abc, }]
else:
    pg = [{'variant': '1',
           'abc': abc,
           'xyz': xyz, },
          {'variant': '2',
           'abc': abc, }]
parameterGrid = ParameterGrid(pg)

def myFunc(myParam):
    print(myParam)

pool = Pool(1)
myList = pool.map(myFunc, parameterGrid)
```

does work if `False`:

```
{'abc': 1, 'variant': '1', 'xyz': 3}
{'abc': 1, 'variant': '1', 'xyz': 4}
{'abc': 2, 'variant': '1', 'xyz': 3}
{'abc': 2, 'variant': '1', 'xyz': 4}
{'abc': 1, 'variant': '2'}
{'abc': 2, 'variant': '2'}
```

and fails with `True`:

```
TypeError: object of type 'MyStrategy' has no len()
```

Comment: Why do you define var1 and var2 as separate enum? It seems to work if you just do `pg = [{'variant': MyStrategy.var1,...` and `{'variant': MyStrategy.var2,...`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, with this I get the error `TypeError: Parameter grid value is not iterable (key='variant', value=<MyStrateg.var1: 1>)`

Comment: Oh my bad, I meant `pg = [{'variant': [MyStrategy.var1],..` and `{'variant': [MyStrategy.var2],...`

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads also to the error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'myFunc' on <module '__main__' (built-in) >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change the values in the enum to strings,since that is the same data type you are using for `variant` key in the `False` block. Like this

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
from multiprocessing import Pool
from enum import Enum


class MyStrategy(Enum):
    var1 = '1'  #<--------Notice the value is string not int
    var2 = '2'
```

Next, use the values like this:

```
var1 = MyStrategy.var1.value
var2 = MyStrategy.var2.value
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `True` example, in the `pg` list of dictionaries, both of the *values* of the `'variant'` *keys* are type `<enum 'MyStrategy'>`. While in the `False` example are type `str`.

To replicate the `False` variant using enumerators, you have to change the following:

```python
class MyStrategy(Enum):
    var1 = '1'
    var2 = '2'

pg = [{'variant': MyStrategy('1').value,  # Or MyStrategy.var1.value
           'abc': abc,
           'xyz': xyz, },
      {'variant': MyStrategy('2').value,  # Or MyStrategy.var2.value
           'abc': abc, }]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this leads to the error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'myFunc' on <module '__main__' (built-in) >`

Comment: Hi @user7468395, my solution replicates the behavior of the `False pg` block using `Enum`. Both `MyStrategy('1').value` return a string so if your `False pg` have worked my solution should also work... However, it seems you are modifying `pg` in `parameterGrid`, I invite you to modify your question including the implementation code of `parameterGrid`. Also you can iterate over an `Enum` object by accessing it like this: `MyStrategy.__members__`, check the documentation out [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration). It is nothing but an _read-only_ `dict`!!

Comment: Hi @jesteras, no I do not anything else apart from what is visible in the question... So, the full code of what I am doing is visible in my question. But how what your overall solution look like regarding `MyStrategy.__members__` that you mentioned in your last comment?